# Grepping a word/phrase in array's index and return the whole array in perl

Tags: arrays, perl

I read an input file and record  is seperated by double new line and 
Storing a chunk (seperated by \n) in array
And while i try to grep a pattern "FEILD BEING REMOVED" , it is actually not picking it
Any issues with the way i am grepping,

```
my @msg = [split /\n/, $input_line ];
my @index_containing_FBR = grep { /FIELD BEING REMOVED/ } @msg; 
print Dumper @index_containing_o;

__DATA__
<ALERT> ID=7 Loss with count of 10 for
    Field Identifier:780222304404
    Address:up.v.000654
    Time: 1468581106

<ALERT> ID=8 Link Loss with count of 15 for
    Field Identifier:780222304404
    Address:up.v.000654
    Time: 1468581114

<INFO>  FIELD BEING REMOVED: an extended period of time - being removed from monitoring
    FIELD Identifier:780222304203
    Time: 146858308
```

Below data has 3 records and each record is seperated by double newline.
And fields in each record are seperated by a single newline, which i am pushing to an array @msg.
And finally iam trying to grep the "FIELD BEING REMOVED" pattern and would like the whole array to be returned.

The above code is not really fetching required stuff.

Please advice

Thanks
Tejas

Comment: `FEILD BEING REMOVED` != `FIELD BEING REMOVED`

Comment: You have a typo in your `grep` expression. `FEILD` != `FIELD`

Comment: @HunterMcMillen , it still doesnt work.

Comment: Please provide a minimal, runnable demonstration of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $file = "d:/test.txt";
my $var;
{
    local $/;
    open my $fh, '<', $file or die "can't open $file: $!";
    $var = <$fh>;
}
my @array = split ( /\n\n/, $var); // you said the information is separated by double \n
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper @array;
```

[This is the content of the @array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svNzJ.png)

```
my @index_containing_FBR = grep { /FIELD BEING REMOVED/ } @array; 
print Dumper @index_containing_FBR;
```

[This is the content of @index_containing_FBR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Sk2w.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is - you may be forgetting that you can set `$/`:

```
my @records = do { local $/ = ""; <DATA> };
print Dumper \@records;
```

(note - setting it to `""` does this in 'paragraph mode' e.g. blank lines separating)

And then you can `grep` by record:

```
print join "\n", grep { /FIELD BEING REMOVED/ } @records;
```