# Data Block in perl not being picked

Tags: perl

Below code works fine, if i get the data from the file
But does'nt really  work if i have same data in the data block
The motto of this script is to search for 780222306003 in array of it starts with a pattern My BEING REMOVED
and search 'up.v.000652',780222304203 if it starts with a pattern LINK BEING REMOVED

Any advises to change the code if any ?

```
use Switch; 
use strict ; 
use warnings; 

use Data::Dumper; 

my $chunk_separator=q(); 
local $/ = $chunk_separator; 
getFirstIntervalReport('MY_W',780222306003,'up.v.000652',780222304203); 


sub getFirstIntervalReport 
{ 
    my ($wssmInstType, $expLinkMy, $expStation,$expectedMyFailure) = @_; 
    my $scan = "on"; 
    # Sort the report files basd on the date in the file name and process each file 
        my @fileData = <DATA>; 
        foreach my $input_line (@fileData) 
        { 
            print "$input_line \n"; 
           my @my_fields =  split /\n/, $input_line ; 
           my $info_containing_My = grep  /My BEING REMOVED/ , $my_fields[0]; 
           my $info_containing_link = grep  /LINK BEING REMOVED/ , $my_fields[0]; 
           if( $info_containing_My ) { 
              print Dumper @my_fields; 
              if( grep  /$expectedMyFailure/ , $my_fields[1]){ 
                print Dumper @my_fields; 
              } 
              else { print "Expected My not deleted \n "; } 
           } 

           elsif ( $info_containing_link && $scan eq "on" ){ 
              if((grep  /$expLinkMy/ , $my_fields[2]) &&  (grep /$expStation/ ,$my_fields[3])){ 
                 $scan = "off" ; 
                 print Dumper @my_fields; 
              } 
              else { 
                  $scan = "on" ; 
                  next; 
              } 
           } 
       } 
       if($scan eq "on") { print " $expLinkMy, $expStation Not Found \n"} 
       } 




__DATA__ 
<ALERT> ID=7 Link Straight info Loss with count of 10 for 
        My Identifier:780222304404 
        Station Address:up.v.000654 
Time: 1468581106 

<ALERT> ID=17 Link Straight info Loss with count of 10 for 
        My Identifier:780222304203 
         Station Address:up.v.000657 
Time: 1468581994 

<INFO>  LINK BEING REMOVED: Link has had no communication for an extended period of time - being removed from monitoring 
for 
        My Identifier:780222304404 
         Station Address:up.v.000654 
Time: 1468582162 

<INFO>  LINK BEING REMOVED: Link has had no communication for an extended period of time - being removed from monitoring 
for 
        My Identifier:780222306003 
         Station Address:up.v.000654 
Time: 1468582562 

<INFO>  LINK BEING REMOVED: Link has had no communication for an extended period of time - being removed from monitoring 
for 
        My Identifier:780222304203 
         Station Address:up.v.000301 
Time: 1468583082 

<INFO>  LINK BEING REMOVED: Link has had no communication for an extended period of time - being removed from monitoring 
for 
        My Identifier:780222304203 
         Station Address:up.v.000654 
Time: 1468583082 

<INFO>  LINK BEING REMOVED: Link has had no communication for an extended period of time - being removed from monitoring 
for 
        My Identifier:780222304203 
         Station Address:up.v.000656 
Time: 1468583082 

<INFO>  LINK BEING REMOVED: Link has had no communication for an extended period of time - being removed from monitoring 
for 
        My Identifier:780222304203 
         Station Address:up.v.000657 
Time: 1468583082 

<INFO>  LINK BEING REMOVED: Link has had no communication for an extended period of time - being removed from monitoring 
for 
        My Identifier:780222304203 
        Station Address:up.v.000656 
Time: 1468583082 

<INFO>  LINK BEING REMOVED: Link has had no communication for an extended period of time - being removed from monitoring 
for 
        My Identifier:780222304203 
        Station Address:up.v.000657 
Time: 1468583082 

<INFO>  LINK BEING REMOVED: Link has had no communication for an extended period of time - being removed from monitoring 
for 
        My Identifier:780222306003 
         Station Address:up.v.000652 
Time: 1468583578 

<INFO>  My BEING REMOVED: Link has had no communication for an extended period of time - being removed from monitoring 
        My Identifier:780222304203 
Time: 1468583082 

<INFO>  My BEING REMOVED: Link has had no communication for an extended period of time - being removed from monitoring 
        My Identifier:780222304454 
Time: 1468583082
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38452025/6594367

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a known problem with `use Switch` and the `__DATA__` block.
Remove the `use Switch` and it will work.

See a [relevant perlmonks question](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=909940) exactly on this. Apprently it's related to how `Switch` module filters the source.

Comment: This sounds interesting, but I think this answer would be improved with a reference.

Comment: Thanks, that works . Any suggestion on the way the data is being processed ?

Comment: @user2256825 Yes, I do have suggestions, but you should have another question for that, since it's a completely different matter.

Comment: @chatterone  It'll be one more possible duplicate if I create another question. Also , I be mentioned suggestion in this question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at this question. I think it's similar with what you need.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38452025/6594367

Adapted to your case :

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $var;
{    
    local $/;
    $var = <DATA>;
}
my @array = split ( /\n\n/, $var); # your information is separated by double \n
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper @array;
```

[image: Here is your content from __DATA__]

From here you can parse your elements like this:

```
my @index_containing_My = grep { /My\sBEING\sREMOVED/ } @array;
....
```

Comment: Not Sure, i would need the edit the question,Also i needed some suggestions about the current code. 
Also , though the code is same, the data block is nt being picked here :)
In the other code, it was the file not the data block

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. Leave a comment with the link on the question, and if you believe it's a duplicate, say so.

Comment: @simbabque sure. , but the code in both are different though they pick the same data, and array creation part, but this has data processing too which is not available in the other . Should I edit the other thread and add this code ?

Comment: No, don't edit your old answer to the other question. If you can provide an answer here that is significantly different from the old one, go ahead. If it's about the inside of the loop, explain that, and don't explain the loop. But _this might help you_ is a comment, not an answer.